# HIVE SQL - row_number() OVER (partition BY

Tags: sql, hive, partition-by

Hi I'm trying to populate the row_number using row_number() over (partition, but the results is not giving me the row number 1 where the first record is cumulative_cost >= threshold and the subsequent rows all have the same row number.

This is the result

| date | cost_amt | cumulative_cost | **threshold_reached_order** | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/07/2023 | 14.09 | 14.09 | 0 | 12345 |
| 9/07/2023 | 10.2 | 24.29 | 0 | 12345 |
| 9/07/2023 | 25.03 | 49.32 | **3** | 12345 |
| 11/07/2023 | 28.09 | 77.41 | **4** | 12345 |

I'm expecting this result

| date | cost_amt | cumulative_cost | **threshold_reached_order** | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/07/2023 | 14.09 | 14.09 | 0 | 12345 |
| 9/07/2023 | 10.2 | 24.29 | 0 | 12345 |
| 9/07/2023 | 25.03 | 49.32 | **1** | 12345 |
| 11/07/2023 | 28.09 | 77.41 | **2** | 12345 |

```
select date, cost_amt, cumulative_cost,
case when cumulative_cost >= threshold then
row_number() OVER (partition BY product_name, userid ORDER BY date, order_id) 
else 0 
end AS threshold_reached_order,
product_id
from table1
where userid = 'ABCDEFG'
order by userid , product_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row_number() OVER (partition BY product_name, userid ORDER BY date, order_id) is a window function that assigns a unique number to each row within a partition, which is determined by the product_name and userid columns. The rows are ordered by date and order_id.

The rows are already given the number and then you are putting the condition.

**Before cumulative_cost >= threshold condition:**

| date | cost_amt | cumulative_cost | threshold_reached_order | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/07/2023 | 14.09 | 14.09 | 1 | 12345 |
| 9/07/2023 | 10.2 | 24.29 | 2 | 12345 |
| 9/07/2023 | 25.03 | 49.32 | 3 | 12345 |
| 11/07/2023 | 28.09 | 77.41 | 4 | 12345 |

**After cumulative_cost >= threshold condition:**

| date | cost_amt | cumulative_cost | threshold_reached_order | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/07/2023 | 14.09 | 14.09 | 0 | 12345 |
| 9/07/2023 | 10.2 | 24.29 | 0 | 12345 |
| 9/07/2023 | 25.03 | 49.32 | 3 | 12345 |
| 11/07/2023 | 28.09 | 77.41 | 4 | 12345 |

You can try using this query:

```
SELECT
  date,
  cost_amt,
  cumulative_cost,
  CASE
    WHEN cumulative_cost >= threshold THEN
      SUM(CASE WHEN cumulative_cost >= threshold THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY date, order_id)
    ELSE 0
  END AS threshold_reached_order,
  product_id
FROM table1
WHERE userid = 'ABCDEFG'
ORDER BY userid, product_id, date, order_id;
```